# How to optimize accessing cost of nested objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to optimize accessing cost of nested objects. I have the following structure (example):

Now I want to access data but the problem is I need to keep on adding loops where every I got nested data. That means if I want to access racks I need to itterate 3 for loops like

```js
var jsonObj=[{
  "shelfs": [
    {
      "Shelf1": [
        {
          "Racks": [
            {
              "Rack1": [
                {
                  "Book1": "Value"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Rack2": [
                {
                  "Book1": "Value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Shelf2": [
        {
          "Racks": [
            {
              "Rack1": [
                {
                  "Book1": "Value"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Rack2": [
                {
                  "Book1": "Value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++)
  {
    var shelfs=jsonObj[i];
    var key=Object.keys(shelfs)[0];
    //var shelfs=arr[arr[0].key];
    //alert(JSON.stringify(shelfs[key]));//shelfs));
    for(var j=0;j<shelfs[key].length;j++)
      {
        var shelfdetails=shelfs[key][j];
        var skeys=Object.keys(shelfdetails);
        for(var k=0;k<skeys.length;k++)
          {
            var racks=shelfdetails[skeys[k]];
            alert(JSON.stringify(racks));
          }
      }
    }
```

Here to access racks information I put 3 nested for loops but eventually it is increasing the time complexity. Please can anybody suggest me better data structure or method to access nested JavaScript objects with low time complexity?

Comment: Do you actually have a measurable performance problem?

Comment: What you have a is an array of objects, *not* JSON. JSON is a **data-format**, like XML or CSV.

Comment: If you don't know the property names of each level, there is not much else you can do but loop. However, you could use recursion and make the code more concise.

Comment: You could do some kind of pre-processing and create a sort of index of everything you're interested in on a new hash. Then you could do lookups against the new hash pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have performance issue, need to optimize object accessing. I don't know property names in each level, they are dynamic. Thanks for suggesting recursion method, but i think still we can't reduce complexity in this scenario.

Comment: *What* do you want to access actually? A specific value (by what)? All values? If you need everything, then looping is totally appropriate.

Comment: Can you quantify your performance problem. i.e. how long does it take to traverse your entire collection?

Comment: @Bergi I need to show all data on GUI. I am getting struggle when it becomes very large data just because of  time complexity becoming n^n. which is very worse in case of mobile devices.

Comment: @prasad: No. Looping over all data is still `O(n)`. Maybe just `n` is becoming too large for the memory of mobile devices?

Comment: The expensive part of displaying information is not the looping over your data structure but is in the DOM manipulation. Iterating over your data as you have shown is not your performance problem.

Comment: @Bergi: In my case I am accessing a multi-dimensional array because my data is in the form of array inside array and array inside array(Shelfs[]->shelfdetails[]->Racks[]->Books[])  like that. I am assuming it as more than O(n) becasue of this arrangement.

Comment: You have n books that you want to display in your UI. It will take n display operations to display n books. It does not matter that they are are in nested loops the total number of display operations is still n.

Comment: @prasad: Assuming `n` is the number of books, then iterating that nested structure is still `O(n)` except you have (many) shelves or racks that do not contain at least one book.

Answer (score 0):

You have n books that you want to display in your UI. It will take n display operations to display n books. It does not matter that they are in nested loops, the total number of display operations is still n. There is no optimization you can perform to reduce the number of display operations you need to perform.

Even if you were to flatten your data structure in to a single flat array of books the number of display operations would still be n.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to optimize accessing cost of nested objects.

Do you mean the CPU cost, the storage cost, or the code complexity cost? The three have quite different implications. Since you go on to say

> I need to keep on adding loops whereever I got nested data.

I am going to assume that you are most interested in code complexity. In that case, consider the following flatter data structure, which might be easier to loop through, to filter, to sort, to group, and to otherwise process using utility libraries such as underscore.

```
[
    { shelf: 'Shelf1', rack: 'Rack1', book: 'Book1', value: "Value"},       
    { shelf: 'Shelf1', rack: 'Rack2', book: 'Book1', value: "Value"},
    { shelf: 'Shelf2', rack: 'Rack1', book: 'Book1', value: "Value"},
    { shelf: 'Shelf2', rack: 'Rack2', book: 'Book1', value: "Value"}
]
```

Abstractly speaking, each `"Book1": "Value"` item has associated with it a shelf and a rack. In your suggested data structure, this "association" is represented by "belonging to" relationships, where it belongs to an array which is the value of a property whose name specifies the shelf or rack. In the above flatter structure, the associations are instead specified explicitly by giving them as properties.

With the flatter structure, if for some reason you wanted to create a data object with keys giving the shelf and values giving an array of objects on that shelf, in Underscore that is as easy as

```
_.groupBy(obj, 'shelf')
```

So all else being equal it seems that the flatter data structure is a more flexible way to represent the data, and you can derive other things you need from it more easily.

Another way to look at it is that currently in order to find the sets of relationships of shelves, racks, and books, you need to iterate through three levels of nested arrays, whereas in the flatter structure the relationships are represented more directly.

Performance, either CPU-wise or space-wise, is rarely going to be a reason to choose one structure over another, unless you are dealing with a huge amount of data. Otherwise, the difference in performance is likely to measured in milliseconds or microseconds, or a few K of storage. You should choose the structure that allows you to represent your algorithms in a fashion which is concise and provably correct. If you intend to handle hundreds of thousands of objects, then in that case yes, you would want to design custom structures optimized for time or space.